# Dumping numpy arrays into neural network

Tags: csv, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to solve the titanic machine learning challenge from kaggle using a neural network. I removed most of the irrelevant data and converted the useful data into a 2D numpy array while the survival is converted into a 1D numpy array. For some reason it throws an error saying dimension 0 in both shape must be equal, I've been trying to solve it for quite a while and I hope that you guys can help out.

TensorFlowNumpy.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

def numpy2tensor(numpy):
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        return tf.constant(numpy)

def tensor2numpy(tensor):
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        return tensor.eval()
```

Dataset.py

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
dataset = pandas.read_csv('train.csv')
dataset2= dataset.drop(['PassengerId','Survived','Name','Ticket','Fare','Cabin','Embarked'],axis=1)
dataset3= dataset2.fillna(0)
survive = pandas.read_csv('train.csv')
survival = np.float32(survive.Survived)
dataset4 = np.float32(dataset3)
```

MainCode.py

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
from dataset import dataset4,survival
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from TensorFlowNumpy import numpy2tensor
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y = train_test_split(dataset4,survival,test_size 
= 0.2)
tensor_train_x = numpy2tensor(train_x)
tensor_train_y = numpy2tensor(train_y)
tensor_test_x = numpy2tensor(test_x)
tensor_test_y = numpy2tensor(test_y)   

n_nodes_hl1 = 10
n_nodes_hl2 = 10
n_classes = 2

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 
n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, 
n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}
    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, 
n_classes])),
                    'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), 
hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), 
hidden_2_layer['biases'])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
output = tf.matmul(l2,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = 
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, 
labels=tensor_train_y))
     optimizer1 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 100
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer1, cost], feed_dict={x:tensor_train_x, 
y:tensor_train_y})
            epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out 
of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

         correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))

train_neural_network(tensor_train_x)
```

Comment: Where is the error and which part of the code throws it?

Comment: The error isn't in my code according to it. The first error is 
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 
    Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 712 and 1 for 
    'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' (op: 
    'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [712,2], [1,712].

Comment: Second error:
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 712 and 1 for 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' (op: 'SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits') with input shapes: [712,2], [1,712].

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this error several times, problem is obviously in our code. I didn't look through your code thoroughly as i am leaving for the day, but i smell that your dependent variable/ output variable shape is [1,712] which should be [712,1] so some where in the code try to fix it. Basically what it meant is you are having one row with 712 columns but it should be 712 rows with 1 column(output). Please mark this as answer if it helps. Ping me tomorrow if problem still exists. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I'm trying to use DNNclassifier and rewrite my entire code, I'm very busy, I will try to update you.